# Unity game app sometimes crashes when resetting

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So I am currently making an android game app and I tried creating a reset button that will reset the level and when I built it and tested it out, it will sometimes crash. I don't know how to check it once I built it into my android phone, but I used this line of code to reset the scene.

```
public void Button_Click()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
}
```

Any ideas on what it could be or how I can check it? It doesn't crash when I am running in Unity, only when it is built.

Comment: do you check your profiler, when you click the reset button look into your profiler, so you can check who is the culprit for the crash